# What does it mean to say that a semisimple Lie algebra is \textit{generated} by root spaces?

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

Suppose that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a semisimple Lie algebra, with root spaces $\mathfrak{g}^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in R$ where $R$ is the associated (reduced) root system for $\mathfrak{g}$. In Humphreys (p. 39), part $(f)$ of Proposition 8.4 says:

> $\mathfrak{g}$ is generated (as a Lie algebra) by the root spaces $\mathfrak{g}^{\alpha}$.

I am unclear as to what the meaning of "generated" is, in this context. Does the content of this statement essentially have the same meaning as the content of the theorem about the Cartan decomposition of $\mathfrak{g}$, or are we saying more/something different here?

Comment: It means every element of $\mathfrak{g}$ is a linear combination of iterated brackets of elements of the $\mathfrak{g}^\alpha$. Or you can say the smallest subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ containing every root space.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Considering we have the root space decomposition of $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e. that $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{g}^0 \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in R} \mathfrak{g}^{\alpha}$, I think that the only extra information in the statement is that any element of $\mathfrak{g}^0$ is a linear combination of brackets of elements of the $\mathfrak{g}^{\alpha}$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.